# How to create dynamic URL page structure in nextjs? if one URL is subset of another URL format

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have two URL matches on react js

1. '/:countryCode([a-z]{2})/:category/:genre'
2. '/:countryCode([a-z]{2})/:category/:genre/:performer'

If it matches with 3 dynamic parameters it redirects to the genre page. If it matches with another one it turns to the performer page.

How can I create a page structure on nextjs.
/pages/[countryCode]/[category]/[genre]/[performer]
How it will works on both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pages/
  [countryCode]/
    [category]/
      [genre]/
        [performer].js //Matches [countryCode]/[category]/[genre]/[performer]
        index.js //Matches [countryCode]/[category]/[genre]/
```

Answer (score -1):

inside genre folder create a file index.js

Comment: Please explain this solution. One-line instructions are rarely helpful for people who are considering multiple solutions. Why will this work?

Comment: well thats how next routing works, in fact not only next, most app works like this,